# How to have three separate animations triggered in the order of hover over, click, and hover out occur to completion in sequential order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, queue

I have a three step animation triggered by hover over, click, and hover out (in this order) that I want to occur to completion sequentially. Each step of the animation must complete before the next animation takes place. Ideally repeating hover over, click, and hover out before the entire animation completes does not queue further animations.

For instance, lets say each animation has a duration of 2 seconds:
User hovers over element to animate for 1 second, clicks, and then hovers out.

The expected behavior should be as follows:
6 seconds of total animation duration with the animation triggered by hover over occurring and completing first, the animation triggered by click occurring and completing second, and the animation triggered by hover out occurring and completing third.

```
$('#elem').hover({
    function() {
        // stepOneAnimation
    },
    function() {
        // stepThreeAnimation
    }
});

$('#elem').click(function() {
    // stepTwoAnimation
});
```

I feel like I should be using queue/dequeue but the documentation is sparse and I'm not quite sure how to tailor the examples to my specific case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What if the user doesn't click?

Comment: It should proceed straight to step three of the animation.